# How to resolve occluded objects issue with OpenCv's trackers and how to improve tracking in fast motion objects?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, tracking

I've been on a project where I have to detect and track the movement of balls around. So, First I'm detecting the balls, attaching them to the OpenCv's object trackers and keep an association between them and newly detected objects in each next frame to see if they are the same. What happens is that when the ball rolls too fast from say left to right, the trackers are not able to follow the ball and furthermore when one balls rolls behind some other ball, the occluded balls tracker also gets assigned to the visible ball(which has now 2 trackers to it) and the occluded ball gets assigned as a new object and new tracker is initialised on it. What can I do to solve this problem.

I even tried MOTI(Multiple Object Tracking) but that did not give me the flexibility to assign each tracker to the new object and so on...

What can I do now???
I'm stuck at using Yolov3 for object detection and OpenCv's trackers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please take this [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64399102/edit) this post to include your own effort into solving the problem, AKA the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution to this is:**

I shifted from feature based tracking algorithms (opencvs') to distance based algorithms. This means we have greater control in a human intuition measure (although now the objects may exchange when too close).

I'm using **Centroid Tracker algorithm** now. It does good with my application. And also I've used a more accurate model for my application i.e., **Mobilenetv2** using transfer learning for my own dataset. Works great with **Nvidia GTX GeForce 1060** **~18 fps**.

Also I'm using

- **tensorflow==2.4** framework,
- **python==3.7**

Stumbled upon a lot of errors while transfer learning but they are by root dependency issues. Resolve all those and you'll update some pre-provided code
to make everything run end-to-end.

Hope this helps someone